# Centering flexbox items

Tags: html, css, templates, center, flexbox

I'm trying to center the content within my flexboxes but whatever I try seems to not work.

such as:

```
align-items: center;
-moz-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;

justify-content: center;
-moz-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
```

This is the template we've been trying to align the flex content:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/idzDE

you'll see all the links labelled box# we've been trying to center in the flex boxes and have yet to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your `.right li` as flexbox as well.

```
.right li {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-align:center;     
    flex:1;
    display:flex; //flexbox
    align-items: center; //center ver.
    justify-content: space-around; //center hor.
}
```

[UPDATED](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wkoJz)

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to this:

```
/* Fonts */

/* Regular */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'League Gothic';
    src: url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.svg#league_gothicregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}



html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
*{
text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    background:yellow;

}

nav,header a{
font-family:'League Gothic';
    font-size:1em;
    color:white;
}

.left{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background:orange;
    width:10%;
}

.left ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:column;



}

.left li{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-align:center;
   flex:1;
  margin: auto;  
}

.left a{
    color:white;


}



.toolBar{
    background:steelblue;
    height:50%;
}

.content{
    background:mediumseagreen;
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;

}

.right{
    display:flex;
    background:orangered;
    margin-left:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:10%;
}

.right ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:column;

}

.right li {
  margin: auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10%

}

.right a {
 color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

}
.topnav-toolbar{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
}

.topnav-toolbar ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;


}

.topnav-toolbar li {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin: auto;

}

.topnav{  
    background:mediumspringgreen;
    height:50%;
}


.right-content-topnav-toolbar{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}

.right-content{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IvKiz)

Comment: to whoever voted this down it would be nice to know why since it does EXACTLY what the question requires, as shown in the Codepen. If this answer is wrong, then explain why